# Brain Segmentation Using U2Net Value Error

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, image-segmentation

I am trying to implement brain tumor segmentation with u2net using keras and tensorflow. My model has trained. But in the testing phase I am getting this error "Value Error: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 3 dimension(s) and the array at index 4 has 4 dimension(s)" in the testing module. I first trained the model with U-Net and then changed the code to U2net. These are my codes. Can anyone help me fix this?

metrics module :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

smooth = 1e-15
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(y_true)
    y_pred = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(y_pred)
    intersection = tf.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (tf.reduce_sum(y_true) + tf.reduce_sum(y_pred) + smooth)

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1.0 - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
```

unet module : (It is u2net. I just named it unet)

```
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Activation, MaxPool2D, UpSampling2D, Concatenate, Add

def conv_block(inputs, out_ch, rate=1):
    x = Conv2D(out_ch, 3, padding="same", dilation_rate=1)(inputs)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    return x

def RSU_L(inputs, out_ch, int_ch, num_layers, rate=2):
    """ Initial Conv """
    x = conv_block(inputs, out_ch)
    init_feats = x

    """ Encoder """
    skip = []
    x = conv_block(x, int_ch)
    skip.append(x)

    for i in range(num_layers-2):
        x = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(x)
        x = conv_block(x, int_ch)
        skip.append(x)

    """ Bridge """
    x = conv_block(x, int_ch, rate=rate)

    """ Decoder """
    skip.reverse()

    x = Concatenate()([x, skip[0]])
    x = conv_block(x, int_ch)

    for i in range(num_layers-3):
        x = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation="bilinear")(x)
        x = Concatenate()([x, skip[i+1]])
        x = conv_block(x, int_ch)

    x = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation="bilinear")(x)
    x = Concatenate()([x, skip[-1]])
    x = conv_block(x, out_ch)

    """ Add """
    x = Add()([x, init_feats])
    return x

def RSU_4F(inputs, out_ch, int_ch):
    """ Initial Conv """
    x0 = conv_block(inputs, out_ch, rate=1)

    """ Encoder """
    x1 = conv_block(x0, int_ch, rate=1)
    x2 = conv_block(x1, int_ch, rate=2)
    x3 = conv_block(x2, int_ch, rate=4)

    """ Bridge """
    x4 = conv_block(x3, int_ch, rate=8)

    """ Decoder """
    x = Concatenate()([x4, x3])
    x = conv_block(x, int_ch, rate=4)

    x = Concatenate()([x, x2])
    x = conv_block(x, int_ch, rate=2)

    x = Concatenate()([x, x1])
    x = conv_block(x, out_ch, rate=1)

    """ Addition """
    x = Add()([x, x0])
    return x

def u2net(input_shape, out_ch, int_ch, num_classes=1):
    """ Input Layer """
    inputs = Input(input_shape)
    s0 = inputs

    """ Encoder """
    s1 = RSU_L(s0, out_ch[0], int_ch[0], 7)
    p1 = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(s1)

    s2 = RSU_L(p1, out_ch[1], int_ch[1], 6)
    p2 = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(s2)

    s3 = RSU_L(p2, out_ch[2], int_ch[2], 5)
    p3 = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(s3)

    s4 = RSU_L(p3, out_ch[3], int_ch[3], 4)
    p4 = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(s4)

    s5 = RSU_4F(p4, out_ch[4], int_ch[4])
    p5 = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(s5)

    """ Bridge """
    b1 = RSU_4F(p5, out_ch[5], int_ch[5])
    b2 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation="bilinear")(b1)

    """ Decoder """
    d1 = Concatenate()([b2, s5])
    d1 = RSU_4F(d1, out_ch[6], int_ch[6])
    u1 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation="bilinear")(d1)

    d2 = Concatenate()([u1, s4])
    d2 = RSU_L(d2, out_ch[7], int_ch[7], 4)
    u2 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation="bilinear")(d2)

    d3 = Concatenate()([u2, s3])
    d3 = RSU_L(d3, out_ch[8], int_ch[8], 5)
    u3 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation="bilinear")(d3)

    d4 = Concatenate()([u3, s2])
    d4 = RSU_L(d4, out_ch[9], int_ch[9], 6)
    u4 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation="bilinear")(d4)

    d5 = Concatenate()([u4, s1])
    d5 = RSU_L(d5, out_ch[10], int_ch[10], 7)

    """ Side Outputs """
    y1 = Conv2D(num_classes, 3, padding="same")(d5)

    y2 = Conv2D(num_classes, 3, padding="same")(d4)
    y2 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation="bilinear")(y2)

    y3 = Conv2D(num_classes, 3, padding="same")(d3)
    y3 = UpSampling2D(size=(4, 4), interpolation="bilinear")(y3)

    y4 = Conv2D(num_classes, 3, padding="same")(d2)
    y4 = UpSampling2D(size=(8, 8), interpolation="bilinear")(y4)

    y5 = Conv2D(num_classes, 3, padding="same")(d1)
    y5 = UpSampling2D(size=(16, 16), interpolation="bilinear")(y5)

    y6 = Conv2D(num_classes, 3, padding="same")(b1)
    y6 = UpSampling2D(size=(32, 32), interpolation="bilinear")(y6)

    y0 = Concatenate()([y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6])
    y0 = Conv2D(num_classes, 3, padding="same")(y0)

    y0 = Activation("sigmoid")(y0)
    y1 = Activation("sigmoid")(y1)
    y2 = Activation("sigmoid")(y2)
    y3 = Activation("sigmoid")(y3)
    y4 = Activation("sigmoid")(y4)
    y5 = Activation("sigmoid")(y5)
    y6 = Activation("sigmoid")(y6)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs=[y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6])
    return model

def build_u2net(input_shape, num_classes=1):
    out_ch = [64, 128, 256, 512, 512, 512, 512, 256, 128, 64, 64]
    int_ch = [32, 32, 64, 128, 256, 256, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16]
    model = u2net(input_shape, out_ch, int_ch, num_classes=num_classes)
    return model

def build_u2net_lite(input_shape, num_classes=1):
    out_ch = [64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64]
    int_ch = [16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16]
    model = u2net(input_shape, out_ch, int_ch, num_classes=num_classes)
    return model

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = build_u2net_lite((256, 256, 3))
    model.summary()
```

train module :

```
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"

import numpy as np
import cv2
from glob import glob
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, CSVLogger, ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping, TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from unet import build_u2net_lite
from metrics import dice_loss, dice_coef

""" Global parameters """
H = 256
W = 256

def create_dir(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

def load_dataset(path, split=0.2):
    images = sorted(glob(os.path.join(path, "images", "*.png")))
    masks = sorted(glob(os.path.join(path, "masks", "*.png")))

    split_size = int(len(images) * split)

    train_x, valid_x = train_test_split(images, test_size=split_size, random_state=42)
    train_y, valid_y = train_test_split(masks, test_size=split_size, random_state=42)

    train_x, test_x = train_test_split(train_x, test_size=split_size, random_state=42)
    train_y, test_y = train_test_split(train_y, test_size=split_size, random_state=42)

    return (train_x, train_y), (valid_x, valid_y), (test_x, test_y)

def read_image(path):
    path = path.decode()
    x = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    x = cv2.resize(x, (W, H))
    x = x / 255.0
    x = x.astype(np.float32)
    return x

def read_mask(path):
    path = path.decode()
    x = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  ## (h, w)
    x = cv2.resize(x, (W, H))   ## (h, w)
    x = x / 255.0               ## (h, w)
    x = x.astype(np.float32)    ## (h, w)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)## (h, w, 1)
    return x

def tf_parse(x, y):
    def _parse(x, y):
        x = read_image(x)
        y = read_mask(y)
        return x, y

    x, y = tf.numpy_function(_parse, [x, y], [tf.float32, tf.float32])
    x.set_shape([H, W, 3])
    y.set_shape([H, W, 1])
    return x, y

def tf_dataset(X, Y, batch=2):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y))
    dataset = dataset.map(tf_parse)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(10)
    return dataset

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """ Seeding """
    np.random.seed(42)
    tf.random.set_seed(42)

    """ Directory for storing files """
    create_dir("files")

    """ Hyperparameters """
    batch_size = 4
    lr = 1e-4
    num_epochs = 500
    model_path = os.path.join("files", "model.h5")
    csv_path = os.path.join("files", "log.csv")

    """ Dataset """
    dataset_path = r"C:\Users\ruthw\Dataset"
    (train_x, train_y), (valid_x, valid_y), (test_x, test_y) = load_dataset(dataset_path)

    print(f"Train: {len(train_x)} - {len(train_y)}")
    print(f"Valid: {len(valid_x)} - {len(valid_y)}")
    print(f"Test : {len(test_x)} - {len(test_y)}")

    train_dataset = tf_dataset(train_x, train_y, batch=batch_size)
    valid_dataset = tf_dataset(valid_x, valid_y, batch=batch_size)

    """ Model """
    model = build_u2net_lite((H, W, 3))
    model.compile(loss=dice_loss, optimizer=Adam(lr), metrics=[dice_coef])

    callbacks = [
        ModelCheckpoint(model_path, verbose=1, save_best_only=True),
        ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=5, min_lr=1e-7, verbose=1),
        CSVLogger(csv_path),
        EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20, restore_best_weights=False),
    ]

    model.fit(
        train_dataset,
        epochs=num_epochs,
        validation_data=valid_dataset,
        callbacks=callbacks
    )
```

testing module :

```
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"

import numpy as np
import cv2
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
from tqdm import tqdm
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.utils import CustomObjectScope
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, jaccard_score, precision_score, recall_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from metrics import dice_loss, dice_coef
from train import load_dataset
from unet import build_u2net_lite

""" Global parameters """
H = 256
W = 256

""" Creating a directory """
def create_dir(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

def save_results(image, mask, y_pred, save_image_path):
    mask = np.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1)
    mask = np.concatenate([mask, mask, mask], axis=-1)

    y_pred = np.expand_dims(y_pred, axis=-1)
    y_pred = np.concatenate([y_pred, y_pred, y_pred], axis=-1)
    y_pred = y_pred * 255

    line = np.ones((H, 10, 3)) * 255

    cat_images = np.concatenate([image, line, mask, line, y_pred], axis=1)
    cv2.imwrite(save_image_path, cat_images)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """ Seeding """
    np.random.seed(42)
    tf.random.set_seed(42)

    """ Directory for storing files """
    create_dir("results")

    """ Load the model """
    with CustomObjectScope({"dice_coef": dice_coef, "dice_loss": dice_loss}):
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model(os.path.join("files", "model.h5"))

    """ Dataset """
    dataset_path = r"C:\Users\ruthw\Dataset"
    (train_x, train_y), (valid_x, valid_y), (test_x, test_y) = load_dataset(dataset_path)

    """ Prediction and Evaluation """
    SCORE = []
    for x, y in tqdm(zip(test_x, test_y), total=len(test_y)):
        """ Extracting the name """
        name = x.split("/")[-1]

        """ Reading the image """
        image = cv2.imread(x, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) ## [H, w, 3]
        image = cv2.resize(image, (W, H))       ## [H, w, 3]
        x = image/255.0                         ## [H, w, 3]
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)           ## [1, H, w, 3]

        """ Reading the mask """
        mask = cv2.imread(y, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        mask = cv2.resize(mask, (W, H))

        """ Prediction """
        y_pred = model.predict(x, verbose=0)[0]
        y_pred = np.squeeze(y_pred, axis=-1)
        y_pred = y_pred >= 0.5
        y_pred = y_pred.astype(np.int32)

        """ Saving the prediction """
        save_image_path = os.path.join("results", name)
        save_results(image, mask, y_pred, save_image_path)

        """ Flatten the array """
        mask = mask/255.0
        mask = (mask > 0.5).astype(np.int32).flatten()
        y_pred = y_pred.flatten()

        """ Calculating the metrics values """
        f1_value = f1_score(mask, y_pred, labels=[0, 1], average="binary")
        jac_value = jaccard_score(mask, y_pred, labels=[0, 1], average="binary")
        recall_value = recall_score(mask, y_pred, labels=[0, 1], average="binary", zero_division=0)
        precision_value = precision_score(mask, y_pred, labels=[0, 1], average="binary", zero_division=0)
        SCORE.append([name, f1_value, jac_value, recall_value, precision_value])

    """ Metrics values """
    score = [s[1:]for s in SCORE]
    score = np.mean(score, axis=0)
    print(f"F1: {score[0]:0.5f}")
    print(f"Jaccard: {score[1]:0.5f}")
    print(f"Recall: {score[2]:0.5f}")
    print(f"Precision: {score[3]:0.5f}")

    df = pd.DataFrame(SCORE, columns=["Image", "F1", "Jaccard", "Recall", "Precision"])
    df.to_csv("files/score.csv")
#%%

The error I am getting : 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ruthw\Unet\test.py", line 80, in <module>
    save_results(image, mask, y_pred, save_image_path)
  File "C:\Users\ruthw\Unet\test.py", line 36, in save_results
    cat_images = np.concatenate([image, line, mask, line, y_pred], axis=1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 3 dimension(s) and the array at index 4 has 4 dimension(s)












I have tried using append, rowstack and column stack function but was unable to figure out how to use them.
```